# how to theme content type based on context

Tags: 8, theming

I have an article content type with categories (term1,term2 etc)
I want to be able to theme the node view with a different theme when specific category is picked on node edit

how can this be done ? any kind of solution is acceptable

NOTE: at this point https://www.drupal.org/project/page_theme, https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey have not been ported to D8 :-( They would really be great solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete solution

1. Installing [context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module we can create a `context` which comprise of conditions which if they are met they do the specified reactions
2. Installing [entity_field_condition](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_field_condition) will let as set the desired condition
3. Add `context` (lets name `alternative theme section`)
4. Add `Node Field (entity_field_condition)` and select category name and choose the specific value that corresponds to the desired category (tid since we are talking about term reference).
5. Add reaction `theme` and choose the theme that you want to be activated on above conditions

NOTES:
At the time of writing this `entity_field_condition` needs a patch to work properly with entity reference (as is the case of category field).  The patch can be found [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_field_condition/issues/2904228)

[term condition](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_condition) was not working at the moment (buggy was not able to add the condition it was giving WSOD)

Alternatives would be to write my own custom condition or debug the `term condition` module or write my [own theme negotiator](https://www.webomelette.com/choose-your-theme-dynamically-drupal-8-theme-negotiation)